# Box truck rental in Vilnius

Tags: rental, car, lithuania

For my upcoming move from Munich to Vilnius, I am considering a rental truck. As I am already in Vilnius and would travel to Munich just to retrieve my belongings, it would be most convenient if I could pick up the truck in or around Vilnius.

The size I am looking at is a 7.5-ton box truck with a tail lift (I have around 30 m³ of goods). In Germany, these are available from most of the major car rental companies, but in Lithuania (and also in Poland) this does not seem to be the case, and I haven’t been able to find vehicles in that class for rent. (This might be because all (West) German driver’s licenses for passenger cars issued until 1998 cover vehicles up to 7.5 tons.)

Any ideas where I can rent a box truck in or around Vilnius?

Comment: I would vote to close this question as off topic, as it is nothing to do with expatriates (a native would potentially ask the exact same question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two car portals which, among others, have rental offers from a variety of vendors:

- https://autoplius.lt, **Skelbimai > Daugiau > Transporto nuoma > Sunkiojo transporto nuoma** (Classified ads > More > Vehicle rental > Heavy transport rental)
- https://autogidas.lt, **Nuoma > Sunkiojo transporto, priekabų nuoma** (Rent > Heavyweight transport, trailers rent)

Prices I have observed are around € 45–60 per day, or € 700–800 per month.